# Prime Faces Data Table With Checkboxes

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I have a Prime Faces data table which has a collection of check boxes. On load some of the check boxes are set to checked and some unchecked. I have some JS logic which is triggered on click - the state returned for both checked and unchecked check boxes is the same - 'Y' and I am wondering why this is the case - anyone have a similar experience ?

Comment: post your XHTML and managed bean code.

Comment: along with what Makky suggested post your js logic also.